# How can I set the vertical slider distance with autoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider, autolayout

How can I set the vertical slider with autoLayout?

I use the

```
  CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*-0.5);
  self.theSlider.transform = trans;
```

code to complete the vertical slider.

But I want to set the slider max position(original horizontally right side) distance the top view30 pt in the every size iPhone.

The slider min position distance the bottom view 30pt in the every size iPhone.

So the slider will stretch.

How can I set the autoLayout code after the CGAffineTransform?

I know how to set the general horizontally situation, I can drag the leading and trailing.

But I don't know how to set the constraint after the CGAffineTransform in objective-c.

Thank you very much.

Comment: During labs in WWDC, they emphasised to not use CGAffineTransform with autolayout.

Comment: If not use CGAffineTransform with autoLayout, how to set the vertical slider with autoLayout,please? thank you.

Comment: Not an exact answer, but I wanted my vertical UISlider to take up 50% of the height of its parent view. I did this  in Interface Builder by Ctrl dragging the slider to the parent view and selecting 'Equal Widths' I then double clicked the constraint and modified 'Second Item' from View.Width to View.Height and then changed the multiplier to 0.5. You might be able to do something similar with Leading.